TV show with a villainous plastic surgeon who ends up getting beat down by a good guy
It's a recent work (last five, maybe ten years), American, and I'm pretty sure it was a TV show, although I can't rule out a movie. I think it was pretty high-budget, it had a pretty Hollywood feel to it. There's a villain, though not the main villain, who I'm 90% sure is a rich plastic surgeon, although he also could have been a fashion mogul...either way, he's had a lot of plastic surgery. I could have sworn he was played by William Fichtner but nothing he's been in seems to fit (it's not "Wrong"). He's really vain and looks like a tall, thin, stereotypical plastic surgery junkie. He wears sunglasses indoors and has black hair.
Eventually one of the good guys confronts him in his office, I think for information, and at first he's dismissive, but then the good guy beats him and threatens to undo all the facial surgery he's had, and he's terrified and gives in to whatever the demands were. I don't think he's seen after that.
The "bad guys" are organized in nature, something like the Mafia. I can't remember any other details.

Sounds like the creepy therapist (and cosmetic surgeon) Dr. Pitlor from season 2 of True Detective. Played by Rick Springfield, he looked very much like William Fichtner after massive plastic surgery and wore sunglasses indoors. In episode 5, an annoyed Ray beats him up to make him talk:

The girls, spill. [...] Kind of day I had. Seeing you pop a few stitches might start to make up for it. Pin-eyed motherf%&$er. Hooker parties. What you'd call affluent men. Caspere attended. Go.



Yeah that's it, thanks!! How on earth is that not William Fichtner though?? Haha
